# $f:B\to\mathbb{R},\ B\subset\mathbb{R}$ bounded increasing function can be extended to an increasing function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, monotone-functions

I have proved the following statement and I would like to know if my proof is correct and/or if it can be improved, thanks.

> Suppose $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $f:B\to\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded increasing function. Prove that there exists an increasing function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in B$.

Let $m, M$ be such that $m\leq f(x)\leq M$ for all $x\in B$ and define $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that

$g(x)=m$ for $x<\inf(B)$ if $\inf(B)\in B$ or $x\leq\inf(B)$ if $\inf(B)\notin B$

$g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in B$,

$g(x)=\sup_{x_0\in B:x_0<x}f(x_0)$ if $x>\sup(B)$ and $\sup(B)\in B$ or $x\geq\sup(B)$ if $\sup(B)\notin B$ or $x\in (\inf(B),\sup(B))\setminus B$.

Then $g$ is an increasing function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, as desired. $\square$

---

EDIT: new proposal after the comments by Kavi Rama Murthy and GEdgar below

$g(x):=\begin{cases}
\inf_{y\in B} f(y) & \text{ for } x\leq \inf(B)\\
\sup_{y\in B:y\leq x}f(y) & \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$

Comment: If $B=\{1,2\}$ then you have not defined your $g$ for points in $(1,2)$.

Comment: My $B$ is not the interval from $1$ to $2$. It is the two point set $\{1,2\}$.. Your proof works only when $B$ is an interval.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have edited the definition of $g$ and now it appears to me that if $f$ is defined on such a set, for example $f(1)=y_1\leq y_2=f(2)$ then $g(x)=y_1$ for $x<1$, $g(1)=y_1$, $g(x)=y_1$ for $1<x<2$, $g(2)=y_2$ and $g(x)=y_2$ for $x>2$. Do you agree?

Comment: I would try $g(x) = \sup\{f(y)\;\mid\;y \le x \text{ and } y \in B\}$

Comment: for the EDIT:  Last line should be $\sup_{\dots} f(y)$ not $f(x)$.  The case $x  \in B$ is then a special case of the corrected last line.

Comment: Maybe defining $g(x)=\text{inf}_{t \in B} f(t)$ for $x\leq \text{inf}\ B$, $g(x) = \text{sup}_{t \in B} f(t)$ for $x\geq \inf B$ and $g(x)=\text{sup}_{ x \geq t \geq \text{inf}\  B 
 \text{ with } t\in B} f(t)$ for $\text{inf}\  B \leq x\leq \text{sup}\  B$ will work

Comment: I suppose that "my extension function" is upper semicontinuous. I liked this exercise. It's worth investigating when this extension is continuous, which is, I suppose, when the original function, here called f, is lower-semicontinuous. Btw, it's a cool exercise.

Comment: @GEdgar thanks! If you would write your comments as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: If increasing means strictly increasing this is false. For example, say $h:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, increasing and bounded, let $B=(-\infty,0)\cup(1,\infty)$, and define $f:B\to\Bbb R$ by $f(x)=\begin{cases}h(x),&(x<0),\\h(x-1),&(x>1)\end{cases}$.

Answer (score 1):

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
This exercise is Exercise 26 on p.40 in Exercises 2B in this book.

I solved this exercise as follows:

> If $B=\emptyset$, then let $g(x)=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}.$
> This $g$ is an increasing function such that $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in B=\emptyset.$
> Suppose $B\neq\emptyset.$
> Let
> $g(x):=f(x)$ if $x\in B$ and
> $g(x):=\sup\{f(t):t\in B, t<x\}$ if $x\notin B$ and $\{t:t\in B,t<x\}\neq\emptyset$ and
> $g(x):=\inf\{f(t):t\in B, x<t\}$ if $x\notin B$ and $\{t:t\in B,t<x\}=\emptyset$ and $\{t:t\in B,x<t\}\neq\emptyset.$
> Let $x,y$ be elements of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x<y.$
> (1) We consider the case in which $x\in B$ and $y\notin B.$
> Since $x\in\{t:t\in B,t<y\}$, $g(x)=f(x)\leq\sup\{f(t):t\in B, t<y\}=g(y).$
> (2) We consider the case in which $x\notin B$ and $y\in B.$
> If $\{t:t\in B,t<x\}\neq\emptyset$, then $g(z)=f(z)\leq f(y)=g(y)$ for every $z\in\{t:t\in B,t<x\}$ because $z<x<y$.
> So, $g(y)$ is an upper bound of $\{f(t):t\in B, t<x\}.$
> So, $g(x)=\sup\{f(t):t\in B, t<x\}\leq g(y).$
> If $\{t:t\in B,t<x\}=\emptyset$, $g(x)=\inf\{f(t):t\in B,x<t\}\leq g(y)$ since $y\in\{t:t\in B,x<t\}.$
> (3) We consider the case in which $x\notin B$ and $y\notin B.$
>
> If $\{t:t\in B,t<x\}\neq\emptyset$, then $\{t:t\in B, t<y\}\neq\emptyset$ because $\{t:t\in B, t<x\}\subset\{t:t\in B, t<y\}.$
> So, $g(x)=\sup\{f(t):t\in B, t<x\}\leq\sup\{f(t):t\in B, t<y\}=g(y).$
>
> If $\{t:t\in B,t<x\}=\emptyset$, then $\{t:t\in B,x<t\}\neq\emptyset$ because $B\neq\emptyset.$
>
> Suppose $y\leq\inf\{t:t\in B,x<t\}$.
> Since $x<y$, $\{t:t\in B,x<t\}\supset\{t:t\in B,y<t\}.$
> Let $z\in\{t:t\in B, x<t\}.$
> Assume that $z\leq y$.
> Since $z\in B$ and $y\notin B$, $z<y$.
> So, $z\in B$ and $x<z<y\leq\inf\{t:t\in B, x<t\}.$
> This is a contradiction.
> So, $y<z.$
> Therefore $z\in\{t:t\in B,y<t\}.$
> Therefore, $\{t:t\in B,x<t\}=\{t:t\in B,y<t\}.$
> So, $g(x)=\inf\{t:t\in B,x<t\}=\inf\{t:t\in B,y<t\}=g(y).$ (Note that $\{t:t\in B,t<y\}=\emptyset$ since $y<\inf\{t:t\in B,x<t\}=\inf\{t:t\in B,y<t\}.$)
>
> Suppose $\inf\{t:t\in B,x<t\}< y$.
> Then, there exists $z\in B$ such that $x<z<y.$
> So, $\{t:t\in B,t<y\}\neq\emptyset.$
> So, $g(y)=\sup\{f(t):t\in B,t<y\}.$
> Then, $g(x)=\inf\{f(t):t\in B,x<t\}\leq f(z)\leq\sup\{f(t):t\in B, t<y\}=g(y).$
>
> Therefore $g$ is an increasing function such that $g(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in B.$